# How do I select an element that is in a different span and is also a class element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a range input and I want the h4 tag to change when I adjust the input. (I would assign an id to the element but I have another set on the same page and I can't seem to get it to work as a class).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="right-side">
    <span> <h4>Sku:</h4> </span>
    <span> <input type="text" size=6 id="sku"/> </span>
    <span> <h4>Condition:</h4> </span>
    <span> <input name = "condInput" type="range" min="1" max="4" step="1" oninput="setCond(this)" onchange="setCond(this)"> </span>
    <span> <h4 class="cond">Good</h4> </span>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
function setCond(t) {
        cond = t.value;
        tag = t.parentNode.parentNode.find("span.h");
        console.log(tag);
        switch(parseInt(cond)) {
                case 1: tag.innerHTML = "Poor"; break;
                case 2: tag.innerHTML = "Fair"; break;
                case 3: tag.innerHTML = "Good"; break;
                case 4: tag.innerHTML = "Excellent"; break;
        } 
}
```

I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get it to work. The console.log returns "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function." I'm still pretty new at coding; any help is appreciated.

Comment: you might want to change the title if you don't want down-voters to attack.

Comment: Note that placing `h4` inside `span` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` is a jQuery method. In vanilla-js, you should use

```
var tag = t.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("span.h");
```

However, that won't work neither because there is no `span` with class `h`, and you want an `h4`.

Therefore, use one of these

```
var tag = t.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("cond")[0];
var tag = t.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("h4")[1];
var tag = t.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("h4.cond");
```

You could also consider things like

```
var tag = t.parentElement.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery "write less, do more" you can use closest() to get specific father eleemnt and later find() to get specific soon eleent

Use var inside function to prevent define or replace global variables

```
function setCond(t) {
        var item=$(t);
        var tag = item.closest(".right-side").find(".h");
        switch(parseInt(item.val(),10)) {
                case 1: tag.text("Poor"); break;
                case 2: tag.text("Fair"); break;
                case 3: tag.text("Good"); break;
                case 4: tag.text("Excellent"); break;
        } 
}
```